# Unable to fetch flickr pictures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, flickr

I'm using gem flickraw with rails - 4.0.0, everything is going good except , when we are fetching photos from flickr  using flikraw it is getting fetched but when I am trying to display it on screen using the url fetched from flickr it is not getting displayed but when I paste the same url in the browser it is getting displayed.

Here is the html code

```
<img src="https://www.flickr.com/photos/USER_ID/14938816417/">
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Th field "USER_ID" needs probably to be changed by a real value...

Comment: Yes I have already used the real user id here...but when I hover the url in firebug it is showing unable to load the given url...but when I paste the same url in new tab image is getting displayed....

Comment: but obviously this url is wrong, so can you provides more details, for example, the url which is not working ?

Comment: here is the url....https://www.flickr.com/photos/116449119@N03/14938816417/

Comment: and how do you generate the link in the view? Are you shure that some caracthers are not transformed during the process (for instance, do you use <%= raw(url) %> ?

Comment: flickr.photos.search(:user_id => "116449119@N03").. It is giving us the list of photos with photo_id and secret...and then we use flickr.photos.getInfo :photo_id => flckr_img["id"], :secret => flckr_img["secret"], It gives the url.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the link to the image page on flickr, not the image url. Your img tag should look something like...

`<img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3888/14938816417_9256faf242_h_d.jpg">`

The code you have is probably using `photo.id` rather than `photo.url_o` (for example)